# KVM/libvirt: Using virtio disk driver in Debian installer

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, virtio

I try to install Debian in a KVM-based VM using the *virtio* disk driver/bus and `virt-install` to run the installer.

However, it seems that the installer lacks the *virtio* driver. Once I switch to `bus=ide`, the installation succeeds and afterwards, I can change back to *virtio*.

Is there any way to let the installer recognize the disk so that I don't have to modify the VM after the installation?

Comment: Use a version of Debian which is still in support. Ancient versions of Debian won't have virtio drivers, in the installer or otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm using Jessie, both on host and VM.

Comment: That should work just fine. Perhaps something is wrong with your media? Have you visited http://bugs.debian.org/ yet?

Comment: Btw. I am using this parameter set for `virt-install`: https://github.com/TYPO3-infrastructure/virtinstaller/blob/f4234ddbd035b424e78869a6d1e40174f998b6c6/virt-install-debian#L81-L94 (the working version with `bus=ide`)